# Can't access to Office365 accout with IMAP & PHP

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to access to office365 inbox, but I am getting this message

```
PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}
```

Here is my code

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
$username = '*****';
$password = '*****';
$fp = fopen('cox_cash [30 40].txt', 'w+');
if (!$fp) die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier");

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to : ' . imap_last_error());
```

Comment: You just posted your userid and password to the Internet. You should consider your email account compromised and change your password immediately. Also, pick a better password.

Comment: Have you tried just doign a 'telnet' to outlook.office365com from your server to see if it isn't firewalled?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was not having the imap library for php. Try using function_exists('imap_open') to check if you actually have the library.
 function_exists() returns true if your php has the function, false otherwise. Simple if statement with echos should do the trick.